# Why would you use redux with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, react-rails, react-on-rails

When I want to code a SPA, I often code the backend (with Node or Rails) and the frontend with React in two distinct projects. The backend spits JSON.

There is these gems: react_on_rails or react-rails, that allow developers to add redux to their project.
Why would you use Redux with Rails if every time you switch pages, the store is emptied out?

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: You use it for when you don't switch pages, either with react routes or just a react app one one single controller action page

Comment: So you mean I HAVE to use react-router on top of rails routing system?

Comment: Yeah if you want multi page app. Also check out ruby-hyperloop.io